# Запутался с макетом

Tags: android, xml

подскажите, разумно ли использовать такую верстку или есть более лучшие варианты? И как сделать чтоб картинка в имидж-батон отображалась полностью? у меня на картинке только кусок изображения. Задавал размеры вручную, не помогло
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:text="@string/europa" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/europa"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/europa" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:text="@string/asia" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/asia"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/asia" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/north_america"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/north_america"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/north_america" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/south_america"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/south_america"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/south_america" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/africa"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center" />
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/africa"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/africa" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/australia"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/australia"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/australia" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом

Comment: используй ConstraintLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вопрос только в картинке внутри `ImageButton`, добавьте в xml вашего `ImageButton` строчку `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`.